# Create new Function in llvm

Tags: llvm

If I have a set of basic blocks  and edges and I need to create for them a new function with new entry and end points.

Could I create this directly in LLVM , just like `createFunction(F)`  then `F.insert(bb, edges)`
which bb is a basic block and edges is the new edges for the new function.

Thanks

Answer (score 6):

You can create a new function with `Function::Create`. See this snippet [from the LLVM tutorial](http://releases.llvm.org/3.5.2/docs/tutorial/LangImpl3.html#function-code-generation) for example:

```
Function *PrototypeAST::Codegen() {
  // Make the function type:  double(double,double) etc.
  std::vector<Type*> Doubles(Args.size(),
                             Type::getDoubleTy(getGlobalContext()));
  FunctionType *FT = FunctionType::get(Type::getDoubleTy(getGlobalContext()),
                                       Doubles, false);

  Function *F = Function::Create(FT, Function::ExternalLinkage, Name, TheModule);
```

Comment: could you clarify to me how to use this snippet in Function Pass,, I need to construct a new function with new basic blocks and new edges extracted from the original function

Comment: @R.Omar: you should not create new functions in a `FunctionPass`, only in a `ModulePass`. Just follow the tutorial I linked to - it explains things pretty well and has complete code for creating functions which you can just use.

Comment: I see , so the main idea is to use this code in Module Pass not Function Pass

Comment: @R.Omar: well, that's an orthogonal suggestion, really. You can also use it outside any pass, of course - if you're just building IR from something else (as the tutorial I pointed to does, or Clang)

Comment: The problem for me is not just create a new function , but also to insert some definite edges between each group of basic blocks

Comment: @R.Omar: after you've created a function, you can add basic blocks into it. Again, look at the tutorial - it's all there. Work through it carefully - it's essential if you want to learn to use LLVM properly

Answer (score -1):

The function create:
http://llvm.org/docs/doxygen/html/classllvm_1_1Function.html#a162a63c89ac118c8ffef75b3a892efa0

How to use the create function in the source code of llvm:
http://llvm.org/docs/doxygen/html/CloneFunction_8cpp_source.html#l00162